# indexPath.row always returns zero

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two collection view and one displays names and the other one displays age of the corresponding person. This data is stored inside array of dictionary in a form of "[["Name","Age"],["Name": "Daniel", "Age" : "20"],["Name":"Jake","Age":"20"]]. This data comes from CSV file, so the first element is a header. Inside collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath, I'm checking collection view and provide data base on row number like cell[indexPath.row]["Name"] and cell2[indexPath.row]["Age"]. However, indexPath.row always returns zero, so I'm getting just headers -

[image]

How do fix this issue? This is my code -

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == self.nameCollectionView {
        let nameCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NameCell

        nameCell.data.text = self.data?[indexPath.row]["Name"]
        println(indexPath.row)

        return nameCell
    }
    else{
        let ageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("AgeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AgeCell

        ageCell.data.text = self.data?[indexPath.row]["Age"]



        return ageCell
    }

}
```

Comment: if you are setting number of Item 1 then how did you got indexPath.row more then 0?

Comment: try to return numberOfitems to self.data.count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As par your code you are setting `numberOfItemsInSection` only 1 then you always get 0th index. make there is dynamic value for example return Array.count.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.data.count  // here you need to set dynamic count of array
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you followed `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` then make your code like following of `cellForRow`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == self.nameCollectionView {
        let nameCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NameCell

        nameCell.data.text = self.data?[indexPath.section]["Name"]
        println(indexPath.section)

        return nameCell
    }
    else{
        let ageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("AgeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AgeCell

        ageCell.data.text = self.data?[indexPath.section]["Age"]



        return ageCell
    }

}
```

Comment: When I do that, I get more than one column which is not what I want.

Comment: First clear with your logic what do you want. and `numberOfItemsInSection` return number of row in particular section. that represent indexPath.row. and `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` that return number of section that represent indexPath.section. Now you need to think and use as par you need

Answer (score 1):

IndexPath is a property which has the following structure
`Indexpath {Section, Row}`.
So if you want your data in two different section with a single row in them then indexpath.row for each of them is going to return 0 as because

For section index 0 - `Indexpath[0,0]` meaning indexpath of section index 0 and row index 0

For section index 1 - `Indexpath[1,0]` meaning indexpath of section index 1 and row index 0

Hope could make you understand.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are telling your collection views that you always have 2 sections and 1 item in each section. Thus the collection view will only ever ask for 1 item in each section. Thus there will only ever BE one item in each section (index 0).

You say "This data is stored inside dictionary in a form..."

Is it a dictionary or an array of dictionaries? A dictionary is an unordered collection, so it is not appropriate for storing an ordered set of items for feeding to a collection view or table view. An array of dictionaries **is** appropriate. From the data you show, and your code, it looks like you have an array of dictionaries. You should edit your question to make that clear.

Your code doesn't really make sense. You have 2 different collection views, and you have each display different data. You tell your collection views that you have 2 sections but ignore the section number and create the same data for both sections. Something is wrong there.

Comment: Sorry It's array of dictionary. All I want to do is display names in one column and ages in the other.